# C# Interop the name does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, excel, interop

I'm using C# Interop to get the Values from an Excel Worksheet depending on a parameter passed to a function and I get the following error:

> the name 'sheet' does not exist in the current context

This is my code:

```
public void getIndexes(int num) 
{
    var wb = (Excel.Workbook)Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook;
    var wsEvars = wb.Sheets["Evars"];
    var wsEvents = wb.Sheets["Events"];

    if (num == 0) 
    {
        var sheet = wsEvars;
    }
    if (num == 2)
    {
        var sheet = wsEvents;
    }

    if (num != 2)
    {
        var rng = (Excel.Range)sheet.Range[sheet.Cells[3, 2], sheet.Cells[3, 25]];
    }
}
```

I suppose that the `sheet` variable should be initialized before the first `if` statement...but which should be the type of this variable since it's a COM Object?

[image]

Comment: It's just an `Excel.Worksheet` in both cases. So `Excel.Worksheet sheet = null;` before the first `if` as you said.

Comment: What if someone passes an `int` value that's not `0` or `2`? Sounds like you might want an `enum` instead.

Comment: The values are passed from another function, and they can be only 0 and 2

Comment: @Equalsk your solution works! You should post it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type you're looking for is [Excel.Worksheet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.worksheet.aspx).

As you correctly surmised you can just declare it before the first `if` statement.

```
public void getIndexes(int num) 
{
    var wb = (Excel.Workbook)Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook;
    var wsEvars = wb.Sheets["Evars"];
    var wsEvents = wb.Sheets["Events"];

    Excel.Worksheet sheet = null; // Declared here

    if (num == 0) 
    {
        sheet = wsEvars;
        // Rest of code
        ...
```

For reference you can hover over the keyword `var` and the tooltip tells you the type it will compile to.

[image]

Comment: One more question...do you also know how I can get the values from the specified range in my code?
I tried with `var wsValues = rng.Value();` but doesn't work

Comment: @Valip Off the top of my head I think it's `var values = rng.Cells.Value;` (it might be `Value2`) and then `values` holds an array of the values. Don't have an interop project on hand to test though.

Comment: It works using `var values = rng.Cells.Value;`, Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you've got a reference set to the Excel interop anyway then declare them like so:

```
Excel.Worksheet sheet = null;
Excel.Workbook wb = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook;
Excel.Worksheet wsEvars = wb.Sheets["Evars"];
Excel.Worksheet wsEvents = wb.Sheets["Events"];
```